# laravel vite compiles scss to empty js file

Tags: vite, laravel-10, php-8.2

I want to use vite in Laravel 10 with scss and vanilla JS with a watcher on a remote server.

- node 20.9.0
- npm 10.1.0
- vite ^4.0.0

Due to reasons, development does not happen locally but on a remote server.
Running `npm run dev` on this remote server, does not work as it is too much expense to configure it.
Fortunately I found out that the `vite build`-command can have a `--watch` flag.

SCSS was set up in this project just by running `npm add -D sass`.
Compiling scss to css basically does work.
Running `npm run dev` locally works, `npm run build` works on the remote server.
CSS is compiled correctly and the HTML is rendered correctly with the respective includes of CSS and JS.

To use the watcher option, I added another script in the `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "beta": "vite build --watch",
    "build": "vite build"
}
```

The problem is, that if I start the watcher on the remote server and modify the scss file
via FTP/ SFTP, vite does not compile it to css but to an empty js-file.
Things get pretty confusing there:

This is the first output after starting the watcher (everythings fine and as expected):

```bash
✓ 7 modules transformed.
public/build/assets/stop-906b2688.svg            0.34 kB │ gzip: 0.22 kB
public/build/manifest.json                       0.80 kB │ gzip: 0.25 kB
public/build/assets/logo-65a56219.png           10.67 kB
public/build/assets/roboto-f6734f81.woff2       15.74 kB
public/build/assets/griffy-f1f5e5e8.woff2       70.00 kB
public/build/assets/techdata.scss-584c0b16.css   0.33 kB │ gzip: 0.24 kB
public/build/assets/techdata.js-14700b47.js      0.03 kB │ gzip: 0.05 kB
built in 413ms.
```

Editing now the scss-file results in this output (empty techdata.scss-4ed993c7.js):
(Editing scss from now on always results inempty js-file)

```bash
build started...
✓ 1 modules transformed.
public/build/assets/stop-906b2688.svg           0.34 kB │ gzip: 0.22 kB
public/build/manifest.json                      0.80 kB │ gzip: 0.25 kB
public/build/assets/logo-65a56219.png          10.67 kB
public/build/assets/roboto-f6734f81.woff2      15.74 kB
public/build/assets/griffy-f1f5e5e8.woff2      70.00 kB
public/build/assets/techdata.scss-4ed993c7.js   0.00 kB │ gzip: 0.02 kB
public/build/assets/techdata.js-14700b47.js     0.03 kB │ gzip: 0.05 kB
built in 19ms.
```

After that editing the `resources/js/techdata.js.js`-file shows this (css now compiled correctly):

```bash
build started...
✓ 2 modules transformed.
Generated an empty chunk: "techdata.js".
public/build/manifest.json                       0.80 kB │ gzip: 0.25 kB
public/build/assets/roboto-f6734f81.woff2       15.74 kB
public/build/assets/techdata.scss-7ed6f43e.css   0.33 kB │ gzip: 0.24 kB
public/build/assets/techdata.js-4ed993c7.js      0.00 kB │ gzip: 0.02 kB
built in 21ms.
```

When starting the watcher and edit the js-file as first change (instead of scss), this output is presented:

```bash
build started...
✓ 1 modules transformed.
Generated an empty chunk: "techdata.js".
[vite:css-post] Plugin error - Unable to get file name for unknown file "32178f1f".
rendering chunks (1)...
```

This happens over and over until scss is edited for the first time of this "watcher-uptime".
After this first scss-change (where scss is compiled to emtpy js-file), the JS change is then correctly processed as shown in the example before.

To make it more confusing: Editing the file directly on the server (without FTP) the watcher works perfectly fine for both scss and JS.

My `vite.config.js` looks like this:
(Fileextension where doubled to check if scss becomes a js-file)

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/scss/techdata.scss.scss',
                'resources/js/techdata.js.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ]
});
```

I already tried to add options in the `vite.config.js` for rollup to add build-delay or smth like that but without any improvement.
What am I doing wrong here? Aren't FTP-changes identically to local changes on the harddrive?